# Product of +1 and -1 with all combinations

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

I am looking for an algorithm or a smart way to do this in excel.

I have this table.

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
-1  -1  -1  -1  1   1
1   -1  -1  1   -1  1
-1  1   -1  1   -1  -1
1   1   -1  -1  1   -1
-1  -1  1   1   1   -1
1   -1  1   -1  -1  -1
-1  1   1   -1  -1  1
1   1   1   1   1   1
```

For statistical reasons, I now wish to create a table with the product of

- All 2-coule of letters
- All 2-coule of letters
- All 3-coule of letters
- All 4-coule of letters

This will be used for testing purposes. It's a 2^(6-3) trial.

So that for example

- row 3 on AB = -1
- row 3 of AC = 1
- row 1 of ABC = -1
- row 2 of EFAB = 1.

I did som initial thinking in excel and I think the permutations will be the list i have written in the botton of the post.

This can either be done in the same sheet, or to create a separate document  2couples.xlsx and 3couples.xlsx

Also nice if this can be done with any number of letters, so I could extend it to ABCDEFGHIJKLMN for example.

I think there will be
$\sum_{i=1}^6 \binom{6}{i}$
in total. Although some of them are duplicates.

A , 
B , 
C , 
D , 
E , 
F , 
AB , 
AC , 
AD , 
AE , 
AF , 
ABC , 
ABD , 
ABE , 
ABF , 
BCA' , 
BCD , 
BCE , 
BCF , 
CDA , 
CDB' , 
CDE , 
CDF , 
DEF , 
DEA , 
DEC , 
DEC' , 
EFA , 
EFB , 
EFC , 
EFD' , 
ABCD , 
ABCE , 
ABCF , 
BCDE , 
CBDF , 
BCDA' , 
etc…

SOMELETTERS' indicates that I could see that it has been calculated before-hand.

Also, note that I saw there was a possibility of shortening this problem by being smart in such a way that D = ABC, E = AB and F = BC.

Comment: Is there any relation between the original data?

Comment: Yes I think it is. Not sure.